# Angular 6 - Add new row in AG Grid

Tags: ag-grid

I want to add a new element in AG Grid. I have a following model:

```
export class PersonModel {
  cars: CarModel[];
}
```

The AG Grid has as `rowData` the array Cars of my model. But this array is not Observable. Now I want to add a new car when I click a button:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onClickCreateCar()">
```

And in my viewmodel:

```
  onClickCreateCar() {
    var emptyCar = new CarModel();
    this.person.cars.push(emptyCar);
  }
```

I can not see the new row in the grid because the array Cars is not observable. It is ok because the property of a model should not be observable. How do you fix the problem?

My AG-Grid definition:

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-fresh" *ngIf="person" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [rowData]="person.cars" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
```

Comment: can you paste your agGrid code here

Comment: maybe the grid refreshes when the reference changes try using `this.person.cars = [...this.person.cars, emptyCar];`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For insert a new row into `ag-grid` you shouldn't use the `rowData` directly it will create\override existing object and all states would be reset, and anyway, there is a method for it [`setRowData(rows)`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#data)

But I'd recommend to use `updateRowData(transaction)`:

> [**`updateRowData(transaction)`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) Update row data into the grid. Pass a transaction object with lists for add, remove and update.

[As example:](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#example-updating-with-transaction)

```
gridApi.updateRowData({add: newRows});
```

Comment: Using the gridApi in the viewmodel is the best practice / best way to work with ag-grid?

Comment: using the `gridApi` is always the best - cuz you no need to worry about the flow of states and so on.

Comment: `updateRowData` is deprecated since AG Grid 23.1, now you should use `applyTransaction`

Answer (score 3):

for angular:

set id for html - selector (#agGrid in this example):

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid 
  style="width: 650px; height: 500px;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and then define the viewchild with this id, import AgGridAngular like shown below, then you can use the ag-grid api in Angular

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-angular-handsometable',
  templateUrl: './angular-handsometable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./angular-handsometable.component.scss']
})
export class AngularHandsometableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridAngular;
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true },
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true },
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true }
  ];

  rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  save() {
    console.log( 'Save', this.rowData );
  }

  addRow() {
    this.agGrid.api.updateRowData({
      add: [{ make: '', model: '', price: 0 }]
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your rowData array is getting updated with the new object you added and if its getting updated and its just a question of updating the grid view, you can explicitly call the refresh API's of the grid.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#refresh

Answer (score -2):

I visited ag-grid documentation and got rowData is simple array. If ag-grid not refreshing your dom then may be they want a fresh array. You can do like this:

```
this.person.cars = [this.person.cars.slice(0), yourNewCarObj];
```

Comment: It works but `[this.person.cars.slice(0), yourNewCarObj];` doesn't work. So it does:
    `var cars = this.person.cars.slice(0); cars.push(yourNewCarObj);`

Comment: I just assumed. If I will create a component for world then definitely i will make sure my component will render as much as fast. They just have good knowledge on changeDetection. This is the way you can develop a project or library that will run super fast.