# Cannot read property 'setQuickFilter' of undefined" in ag-grid Vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I try to filter the ag-grid by using a select box. The grid definition is:

```
<ag-grid-vue id="myGrid" style="width: 1140px; height:500px"

   class="ag-theme-balham"
   :columnDefs="columnDefs"
   :rowData="rowData"
   :enableSorting="true"
   :enableFilter="true"
   :pagination="true"
   :paginationPageSize="10"                                    
   :setQuickFilter="quickFilterText"
</ag-grid-vue>
```

Data Part is :

```
data() {
            return {
                columnDefs: null,
                rowData: null,
                quickFilterText: ''
     }
```

and i try to capture the value of select box on watch in Vue:

watch: {

```
    filter: {
        handler: function (filter) {
            {
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    let companyNames = this.$refs.company.getSelectedValue();
                    this.quickFilterText = companyNames;
                    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(this.quickFilterText);
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                        let gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
                        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

after i select in select box then i see the error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'setQuickFilter' of undefined"

any one can help me? thank you

Comment: can you share your data properties? where is this `gridOptions` coming from?

Comment: this is my data part:
 data() {
            return {
                columnDefs: null,
                rowData: null,
                quickFilterText: '',
}

Comment: where are you declaring and initializing gridOptions? The problem is with it's initialization, because it's property `api` is undefined

Comment: Oh you mean i need to declare separate because i taught when we define in <ag-grid-vue> is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764888/4483102)

You need to use `gridReady` function to bind `gridApi` to the local property.

Once you will bind it, you would be able to use 
 `this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(this.quickFilterText);`

Answer (score 0):

We will set grid params onGridReady and then we will access setQuickFilter to set filter value to filter the grid in the following way

```
const Component = ({dataset, searchTerm}) => {

    const [ gridParams, setGridParams ] = useState()

    const onGridReady = useCallback(params => {
        setGridParams(params)
    }, [])

    const getRowNodeId = useCallback(params => params.data.id, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isEmpty(gridParams)) {
            gridParams.api.setQuickFilter(searchTerm) // setting filter input value
        }
    }, [ searchTerm, gridParams ])

    return (
        <div style={{height: 'calc(100vh - 139px)', position: 'absolute', width: '100%' }}>
            <Grid
                onGridReady={onGridReady}
                rowData={dataset}
                floatingFilter
                sideBar={GRID_SIDE_BAR}
                frameworkComponents={{
                    DateFilter,
                    DateFloatingFilter,
                    NumberFilter,
                    NumberFloatingFilter,
                    SetFilter,
                    SetFloatingFilter,
                    StringFilter,
                    StringFloatingFilter,
                }}
                licenseKey={'test'}
                getRowId={getRowNodeId}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                cacheQuickFilter={true}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

Component.displayName = 'Client.Refresh.GridPanel'

Component.propTypes = {
    searchTerm: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Component
```