# AG-Grid: Cannot update field in Grid as it is read only

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to update a field in ag-grid and it keeps coming back with ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '[object Object]'.

It allows me to edit the cell but when i try to update it comes up with this error.

I am using an observable from an ngrx store to populate the rowData as below:

```
this.order$.subscribe(order => {
            this.order = { ...order, products: [...order.products] };
        });
```

I have checked the above and I can update this object by saying this.orders.products = [] which says to me it is no longer immutable.

```
 <mi-ag-grid [data]="order.products" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [suppressClickEdit]="false"></mi-ag-grid>

columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Code',
            field: 'code',
            width: 150
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Name',
            field: 'name',
            width: 200,
            editable: true
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Quantity',
            field: 'quantity',
            width: 150,
            editable: true
        }
    ];
```

I next tried suggestion from @GreyBeardedGeek and tried to set value with a valueSetter as per below, but still getting same error.

```
,
    {
        headerName: 'Quantity',
        width: 150,
        editable: true,
        field: 'quantity',
        valueSetter: quantityValueSetter
    },


function quantityValueSetter(params): any {
console.log(params);
params.data.quantity = params.newValue;
```

}

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764888/4483102) post

Comment: I left an expanded answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269113/aggrid-in-react-redux-app-is-modifying-underlying-data

Answer (score 8):

The object that you are getting from the store and using in the grid is immutable.

By default, when you make a column in the grid editable, it will attempt to update the backing object directly, and this is the problem that you are seeing - the grid attempts to mutate an immutable object.

The solution is to add a "valueSetter" property to the grid column's definition. The value of this property should be a function that will receive the new value, and then use that new value to update the store.

When you have this property set, ag-grid will not try to update the object directly.

Comment: Thanks :-) Been trying to work that out all day.  Will spend some time tomorrow working through that

Comment: Hi i tried a few things today with no luck, I am not trying to update the store at this stage as they are just local changes before i want to commit to an update to the store.  Hence i tried making the object mutable which i tested to make sure i can change the object and i can but when it comes to ag-grid it still comes back and says I cannot make a change as it is read only

Comment: Ok finally got it working for some reason this.order = { ...order, products: [...order.products] }; was not really making it immutable.  I have written some more verbose code creating a new object by looping through this.order.products.  I will spend sometime cleaning up the code and then post the solution.  Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek you put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with React and Redux toolkit.
I also tried value getter/setter at column definition and no luck. However,I found a blog at AG Grid and a solution.
https://blog.ag-grid.com/adding-removing-rows-columns-ag-grid-with-react-redux-toolkit/

What was missing is value setter at 'defaultColDef' and call redux reducer to update the value. Hope this helps.

```
defaultColDef={{
            minWidth: 100,
            valueSetter: saveNewValue,
            flex: 1
          }}
const saveNewValue = params => {
let field = params.column.colId;
let newRow = { ...params.data };
newRow[field] = params.newValue;
dispatch(updateRow(newRow));
return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only) originates from trying to assign the row data object, which is a read only object, in a flow that will try to change it.

I had the same trouble when trying to use `onCellValueChanged` with the row data to set a recoil atom:

```
const setEntries: SetterOrUpdater<{name: string, age: number}[]> = useSetRecoilState(entriesAtom);
...
const columnDefs: [
    ...
    editable: true,
    onCellValueChanged: (event: NewValueParams<{name: string, age: number}>) => {
        setEntries(entries => [...entries, event.data])
  },
]
```

It was solved after I've cloned the `event.data` object. So I've replaced:

```
setEntries(entries => [...entries, event.data])
```

to:

```
setEntries(entries => [...entries, {...event.data}])
```