# How to prevent ag-grid inline cell editing from modifying row data automatically

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid, immer.js

`AgGrid` by default modifies underlying row data when inline editing is done.

This breaks "immutability rules", as my model is stored in redux. As I'm using `immer` , I am also getting

> Cannot assign to read only property 'version' of object '#'

How can I prevent `AgGrid` from automatically submitting values to the model. I want to manually dispatch an action to the store that will make the changes.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution is to add a "valueSetter" property to the grid column's
>   definition. The value of this property should be a function that will
>   receive the new value, and then use that new value to update the
>   store.

Original answer: [AG-Grid: Cannot update field in Grid as it is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572072/ag-grid-cannot-update-field-in-grid-as-it-is-read-only/53572148#53572148)