# Ag-grid | Cell value is not updating in grid using valueSetter

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I just wanted to give the functionality of edit in my grid and my data was coming from a NGRX state. So, I was not able to edit directly because it was throwing an error saying that can't assign value to read-only object. So, after searching on stackoverflow, I found this [AG-Grid: Cannot update field in Grid as it is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572072/ag-grid-cannot-update-field-in-grid-as-it-is-read-only).

So, I'm just trying to use this valueSetter as suggested in the post in the following way:-

```
this.columnDefs = Object.assign([], this.columnDefs);
console.log('coldDef init ', this.columnDefs);
this.columnDefs = this.columnDefs.map(obj=>({
  ...obj,
  valueSetter: (params:any) => {
    console.log("##newValue##",params.newValue);
    const paramsCopy = {...params.data}
    paramsCopy[obj.field]=params.newValue;
    console.log(params);
    params.data=paramsCopy;
    console.log(params);
    return true;
  }
}));
```

In the logs I can see the new value.

[Please click here to see logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvyZs.png)

But, I can't see my new value on the grid. Am I missing something?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thank you!!

Comment: just writing `params.data[obj.field] = params.newValue` would not work?

Comment: But I can see the updated value in the console.

Comment: I see you are creating a shallow copy of your data and maybe this confuses AG Grid and it does not know that cell to update because the whole data has been updated. Try setting the property of the data object without creating another data object

Comment: AG Grid has a kind of change-detection mechanism which updates cell's value when you return true from the `valueSetter` method

Comment: if I'm trying this:
params.data[obj.field]=params.newValue;
getting following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'title' of object '[object Object]'
    at valueSetter (generic-grid.component.ts:103)

Comment: There is also an `api.refreshCells()` that might help you, but I'm not sure...

Comment: tried that too, but no gain.....

Comment: Did you got any solution, If yes please post